# Using an Apex Repeat in a Visualforce template, do not include particular data from that field

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have this visual force template that is creating a repeat on the below field.  However I don't want it to include BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c  =  'Email Sent' within the email body but to include all other actions. Would I need to develop a class to do this?

The visualforce template include the following:

```xml
<apex:repeat var="ih" value="{!relatedTo.BMCServiceDesk__Incident_Histories__r}">
<tr>
          <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c} </b></td>
          <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__date__c} </b></td>
          <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__note__c} </b></td>
          <td><b>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__userId__c} </b></td>
</tr>             
</apex:repeat>
```

so my email looks like a tabled list:

[image]

Any help to remove this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to use a VF component and embed it in that VF email template. That's because component can have a controller (email template cannot).

It would allow you to write your own query for that list, filter & sort the items in the order you want...

But if you have only handful of items (less than 1000) then you can use "rendered" tag to conditionally display them. It's bit of a hack but should work OK.

Experiment with something like this:

```xml
<apex:repeat var="ih" value="{!relatedTo.BMCServiceDesk__Incident_Histories__r}">
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c != 'Email Sent'}">
        <tr>
          <th>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__actionId__c}</th>
          <th>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__date__c}</th>
          <th>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__note__c}</th>
          <th>{!ih.BMCServiceDesk__userId__c}</th>
        </tr>
    </apex:outputPanel>             
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is a massive help.  I will definately look into writing a component, although my only concern is writing a test which I am not totally sure how to do to allow it to deploy